# How to connect twitter-client application in android

Tags: android, twitter

Previously i was working on how to connect an android application to twitter and posting a tweet but all the things that i have done is when twitter application is browsable. But now i want to do all the things when twitter application is client. Just give me an idea or something how could i do it.

On browsable app. all things are working fine for me but have no idea when application is client all the time getting 401 error, i know using callback url but it work only when application is browsable, i cant get the thing when application is client...any suggestions?

Using this OUT_OF_BAND i am able to get into the login page but cant able to get the authorization token for further use when i press the back key main activity comes but having no authorization token.

```
authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, oauth.signpost.OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);
```

Comment: @piyush: still you are not done with twitter integration? anyways tell me do you want twitter integration with native twitter android application now?

Comment: @ zoombie: :) thanks for your kind support for me actually i was doing the things correctly from the very first day and my application is working fine when twitter application is browsable but whenever i make it client i cant. Actually the thing is our I-Phone team already made an application it have a link to share something on twitter and i am trying to implement the same thing in android but the twitter application that was register by the I-phone team is client i cant change it to browsable...........:(

Comment: @zoombie: Do you have any other suggestion how could i do if the twitter application is client....

Comment: @piyush: i faced same issue, but to overcome it, you have to register seperate applications for android & iphone... as iphone is client application, android appln should be register as browsable by providing callback url at time of register

Comment: @Zoombie: i am able to get into login page using oauth.signpost.OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND but cant able to get the token when i press a back key to get back into main activity page.

Comment: @piyush: steps i have provided are with call_back url, which is only possible if you have application registered on twitter with browsable capability and call_back url. if you hve implemented call_back url and manifest is deployed like i have told, then onNewIntent() callback method is called and no need for press back key too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are talking about the following setting for your Twitter app:

Application Type:  Client ---  Browser

If you are developing an Android application you should use Browser (like you say you did before). It simply will not work with Client. Could you please explain why you are trying to change to Client?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Toffer: thats exactly i want to ask. Currently i am working on an application that our I-phone team already made it and its an working application for them and they are using client i cant change it from client to browsable client is working for them now i have to make exact same application in android having the same application setting and its client right now... :((

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this but from what I managed to find out when I investigated the same issue for an iPhone to Android port, is that it's not going to work. You need to use Browser, end of story. My suggestion is that you create a new Twitter app for the Android version.

Comment: i can't use another application i have to manage the things somehow i just edit my answer like using OUT_OF_BAND, i am able to get into login page but cant able to get the token, i know heres callback url plays it role but any other way........if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
Intent connectSocN/w = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    connectSocN/w.setType("text/plain");
    connectSocN/w.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Subject of message");
    connectSocN/w.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Message to send");
    connectSocN/w(Intent.createChooser(connectSocN/w, "Share"));
```

By using this intent you can get all varieties of socil network that has been installed in your device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer hari but my question is something different, read carefully.